# Error installation Drupal 8 - LogicException: Cannot change the ID of an active session

Tags: drupal, installation, drupal-8

Server:
Centos 7 + nginx + php-fpm

[root@centos ~]# php -v
PHP 7.0.16 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2017 10:25:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.16, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Try install Drupal 8

After step config connect to DB this error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

i fix this

problem in php.ini

drupal try up the session, and dont check if this alredy exist

change line in php.ini

```
session.auto_start = 0
```